# How to get links within a subelement in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following html code:

```
   <div id="category">    //parent div
    <div class="username"> // n-number of elements of class username which all exist within parent div
      <a rel="" href="link" title="smth">click</a>          
    </div> 
    </div>
```

I want to get all the links witin the class username BUT only those within the parent div where id=category. When I execute the code below it doesn´t work. I can only access the title attribute by default but can´t extract the link. Does anyone have a solution?

```
  a = driver.find_element_by_id('category').find_elements_by_class_name("username")
    links = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in a]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following css selector which will return all the anchor tags.

```
links = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"#category > .username >a")]
```

Or

```
links = [x.get_attribute("href") for x in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#category > .username >a")]
```

Comment: Correction: I get an empty list back for some reason

Comment: When I copy the CSS selector I get only the specific selector for this one element. 
There are also multiple classes between the id and class. Do I have to consider this too?

Comment: @MaxFrost : Copy the entire code not only css selector. If you see in my code I have used  `find_elements()` Please make sure elements are loaded properly.

Comment: Thank you! I just had to copy the whole path from the css file :)

Comment: @MaxFrost : I need the access of your webpage and would like to know how you wanted to display the links as a result. I appreciate if you post another question with more clarity about your use cases and expected result and please provide the url if not the case then more html as a reference. Thanks.